# AM/PM date formatting in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, date, jqgrid

I'm having trouble figuring out where I'm going wrong with this date formatting on jqGrid.  I pass in the date formatted by C# as `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` which produces `01/20/2012 10:01:26 PM`.

In my jqGrid I apply formatting as follows:

```
colModel: [
...
    { name: 'EndTime', index: 'EndTime', sorttype: 'date', formatter:'date', formatoptions: {srcformat:'m/d/Y h:i:s A', newformat:'m/d/Y h:i:s A'} },
...
],
```

This is working fine for everything except the AM/PM.  It's always showing AM in my grid.  From jqGrid's documentation, it looks like this should be the right format.  Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.  I changed the formatting in C# to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and my colModel to `formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s', newformat: 'm/d/Y h:i:s A' }`.

The source format is the ISO8601Long format.  I did not use 'ISO8601Long' since I'm using local data and want to sort.