# jqGrid date formatting generates wrong AM/PM

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have column in a jqgrid modeled as follows:

```
colModel: [
          ...
          { name: 'TranDate', index: 'TranDate', search: false, width: 150, 
            sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', 
            formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s A', newformat: 'd-M-Y h.i A'} },
         ...
         ],
```

Data returned from JSON has the following format `2012-07-06 3:25:19 PM` but when the displayed on the grid using the above formatting, it switches the `PM` to `AM` except for times between `12:01` to `12-59`.

This question is similar to [AM/PM date formatting in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203678/am-pm-date-formatting-in-jqgrid?rq=1) but even after making modifications, the problem persists.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the [`DateFormat`](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/jquery.fmatter.js#L124) function in jquery.fmatter.js does not support AM/PM in `srcformat`:

```
    // Tony Tomov
    // PHP implementation. Sorry not all options are supported.
    // Feel free to add them if you want
    DateFormat : function (format, date, newformat, opts)  {
```

Specifically, you can see below that there is no support for the `A` option when parsing the given date:

```
        } else {
            date = String(date).split(/[\\\/:_;.,\t\T\s-]/);
            format = format.split(/[\\\/:_;.,\t\T\s-]/);
            // parsing for month names
            for(k=0,hl=format.length;k<hl;k++){
                if(format[k] == 'M') {
                    dM = $.inArray(date[k],dateFormat.i18n.monthNames);
                    if(dM !== -1 && dM < 12){date[k] = dM+1;}
                }
                if(format[k] == 'F') {
                    dM = $.inArray(date[k],dateFormat.i18n.monthNames);
                    if(dM !== -1 && dM > 11){date[k] = dM+1-12;}
                }
                if(date[k]) {
                    ts[format[k].toLowerCase()] = parseInt(date[k],10);
                }
            }
            if(ts.f) {ts.m = ts.f;}
            if( ts.m === 0 && ts.y === 0 && ts.d === 0) {
                return "&#160;" ;
            }
            ts.m = parseInt(ts.m,10)-1;
            var ty = ts.y;
            if (ty >= 70 && ty <= 99) {ts.y = 1900+ts.y;}
            else if (ty >=0 && ty <=69) {ts.y= 2000+ts.y;}
            timestamp = new Date(ts.y, ts.m, ts.d, ts.h, ts.i, ts.s, ts.u);
        }
```

You have a few options. If you can modify the web service you can have it return the dates in a different format (such as a unix timestamp) or have it return a new date column in a supported format. Alternatively you can report this as a jqGrid bug and/or fix this section of the code to support AM/PM specifiers.

Comment: Your link has been an eye opener and thanks for this. I find the first option easier to implement and return the required format from the server. As long as there is a workaround, I don't think it is critical to open a bug report. Again reading the opening comments on the link maybe there was a reason no to try and implement any conceivable option or format.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why it is doing like this because it is assuming your time as 24 hours clock. Your code should fix it, but i can't find what is wrong with it.

But,Here this will fix it for you

just replace this

```
formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s A', newformat: 'd-M-Y h.i A'} },
```

with this

```
datefmt: "Y-m-d h:i A"
```

here you wont be able to change 'Y-m-d' to 'd-M-Y'.

Comment: Replacing with `datefmt: "m/d/Y h:i A"` displays the data just as it is in the returned JSON format (`2012-07-06 3:25:19 PM`). What I want is for the displayed to appear as `06-Jul-2012 3.25 PM`.

Comment: if you can send the data in 24 hours clock from server than your earlier code will fix AM/PM issue

Comment: I found it easier to format the date from the server side. That way, I only need to format it once in the format I require and avoid the need to specify the format again while displaying on the grid.